# Using an optical mouse sensor for odometry?

Tags: sensors, visual-odometry

I'm trying to use a mouse sensor for odometry on my robot. Most datasheets I have found use SPI or SDIO interfaces for communicating but my microcontroller would require an I2C interface. Would it be possible to bridge this, preferably by not using an IC?

Here are some links to the datasheets I have found:

- [ADNS-2610](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/520966/AVAGO/ADNS-2610.html):
- [ADNS-3080](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/203609/AVAGO/ADNS3080.html):
- [PAW3309DH-TKSL](https://www.pixart.com/products-detail/109/PAW3309DH-TKSL) - This one apparently uses an I2C but I could not find any datasheets or retailers so I cannot confirm it

If you know some other mouse sensors that use I2C I'd be more than happy to hear suggestions

Comment: Which microcontroller?

Comment: @Ben It is a [REV Expansion Hub](https://www.revrobotics.com/rev-31-1153/).